# Merge optimization on Azure Databricks

Tags: apache-spark, pyspark, databricks, azure-databricks

I am trying to optimize the performance of merge in Databricks(DBR 12.2 - so low shuffle merge is enabled). The target table has ~700m rows and the delta has 100-200k rows. This operation is seems slow taking around 30 min with two workers(Standard_D4s_v5 - 4 cores,16 GB RAM).

The problem seems to be the merge id which is a long string of numbers, e.x 060372015102700977000. I even changed target table layout with Z-Order but the distribution is such that almost all the underlying files are being touched.Almost all the target rows are being copied for processing. Decreasing the size of each file did reduce the fraction of files being touched but the performance was similar.

I also created a new column with just the first 5 characters of the merge key and partitioned the table using that column. This did result in skewed file size(and more files) but the partition match between source and target table was around 60%. Merge with this also resulted in lesser number of target rows being copied. But this took more than twice the time.

Why did the performance decrease with partitioning. Also, is there a way to increase performance without increasing computing resources?

Edit: Snapshot of merge metrics[image]
[image]
[image]

Comment: are the merge/row id's in any way related i.e. do inserted rows have similar id's?  This, and not using far slower strings, was one of the reasons I created [unique_id](https://sparkutils.github.io/quality/0.1.1/advanced/rowIdFunctions/#guaranteed-unique-id-how)'s, searching for rows _should_ be far quicker when they are in the first 32 fields.  That said, although it looks like you've done the normal things, can you show the plan (picture and text)?

Comment: no the merge id's seem random coming from the source data. the merge key is within the first 32 cols so the min, max stats for data skipping is available. By plan do you mean query plan because the spark UI just shows me == Physical Plan ==
Execute MergeIntoCommandEdge (1)
   +- MergeIntoCommandEdge (2). I'll edit the Q with snapshot of metrics

Comment: yeah the plan should also show how the data is sourced and distributed but that extra info you added is also interesting.  Rows updated 86k, rows inserted 90k, are these updates on a partition level?  If so would [replaceWhere](https://docs.databricks.com/en/delta/selective-overwrite.html#replace-where) be better?

Comment: also as you are using Azure is both the source and target locations on the same adls gen2 account?  You may be hitting it's concurrency limits, look at app monitor for the utilisation during the timeframe your query runs

Comment: this upsert was without any partition. Only z-order was performed by merge key. Both the tables are in the same schema in hive metastore that is part of databricks workspace so should be in the same managed location.

Comment: the above shows skipping seems unused, did you run optimize after reordering the columns (I've found you need to)? also how many files are there for this target table?

Comment: yes this is one of the tests I ran. This is after I ran Optimize table Zorder by. The issue it seems that even though the rows in source is small the merge id distribution is such that most of the files are touched. I even tried to decrease the file size to 32mb in which case only 550m rows were rewritten but the number of files increased to 4500 and the job became slow.

Comment: Also I saw that the query for which metric are posted in Q has sub execution id and the longest time there is taken by the query which is rewriting unmodified rows.

Answer (score 0):

Given, as you note in the comment, and is backed by target files skipped being 0 , all file partitions parts / blocks are hit by the update.  Unless you can find a way to break up the source and target files along a useful partition you probably cannot improve performance.

657m rows are untouched but have to be written again due to this, with only 86k updated and 94k inserted.

If it's more update than read heavy (and you have to read every file due to no useful partitioning) it's possible moving to an SCD style model and always appending would be better (i.e. add an operation column and use either a received timestamp or another table to generate an operation id etc.).